# Is code coverage displayed in Xcode 7

Tags: xcode, testing, xctest, xcode7

There are strange numbers on the right hand side of my Xcode 7 that I can't figure out what they are.  Could these 0 1 2 numbers on the right side of Xcode 7 perhaps show the number of times a function is tested?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those numbers are part of Xcode's code coverage statistics. In your screenshot the number on the right side shows the number of times the block of code was exercised when running your unit tests.